# Loop through JavaScript object and return new object with modified value

Tags: javascript

I have an object which I am forming with all the input values from a form. I want to go through the object and change all the input value to lowercase before I make a post request to the backend. I want to write a function that takes that object and returns a new object with lowercase value

```
const obj = {name: 'Test', city: 'London'}
const modifiedObj = myFunction(obj)
```

`modifiedObj` should be:

```
{name: 'test', city: 'london'}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ? can please show us code ?

Comment: what does your `myFuncion` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of your object, then iterate through them and access each property.

```
function myFunction(object){
  const newObj = {};
  cons keys = Object.keys(object);
  for(const key of keys){
    if(typeof object[key]!=="string"){
      newObject[key] = object[key];
      continue;
    }
    newObj[key] = object[key].toLowerCase();
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

Comment: I just need to make little change to make sure that I call toLowerCase() only to string value

Comment: @Prabs If it is possible that values are not strings, then certainly, your method works. Would you like me to edit that into my answer?

Comment: `const toLowercase = object => {
  const keys = Object.keys(object);
  const newObject = {};

  for (const key of keys) {
   const value = typeof object[key] === 'string'? object[key].toLowerCase(): object[key]
   
   newObject[key] = value
  }
  return newObject;
};`